# How do I put timestamp on bottom 3 thumbnails?

Tags: html, css, css-position

[Youtube replica timestamp problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJPJY.jpg)

I made a class with position: absolute to apply timestamp on the thumbnails. It worked for the first 3 only the rest 3 didn't make it. The thumbnail-row position is relative. I added time in div after every thumbnail in HTML.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without seeing your code and where the problem exists exactly? Also, it appears you are creating some sort of a browser extension?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi there , welcome to the stack overflow community.
>
> I hope this helps, if not feel free to comment below and I recommend
> going throught this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of questions.

Here is a example of how you should do it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.video {
  width: 360px;
  height: 170px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.videoContainer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.timestamp {
  max-width: min-content;
  background: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  color: white;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoContainer">
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9bZkp7q19f0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="img 1" />
    <div class="timestamp">5:00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-psd/business-youtube-thumbnail-design-template_475351-263.jpg?w=2000" alt="img 2" />
    <div class="timestamp">6:15</div>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://img.pikbest.com/backgrounds/20210520/modern-youtube-thumbnail-design_5939729.jpg!bwr800" alt="img 3" />
    <div class="timestamp">1:30</div>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9bZkp7q19f0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="img 4" />
    <div class="timestamp">5:30</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above snippite.
The parent video `class` has a `position:relative;`, and the images has the `position:absolute;` since it should cover the whole video area.
Now, for the timestamp:
the `margin` property with its auto value is used to send the object to the another side.

*This problem you are facing are probably caused by the mismatched tags in html. Since, some of them are generating correct result. Or you may have implemented a wrong structure, In anycase above snippite may help you.*

> Ask anything you don't understand in comment.

Thank you !